# Need to know custom code to display random and most viewed posts in wordpress posts and pages

Tags: posts, wp-query, widgets, order, statistics

My focus is to use custom but an optimized code to display random and top posts/pages in my WordPress. I have seen some recommendations where people refer to plugins, but I need codes/query only.

Comment: Do you have any working code you need help with or are you just requesting free work? Please edit your question and add in any code you have tried / need help with.

Comment: @Howdy_McGee

You just wrote what I want to write on all questions like this. I will live vicariously through your example. Thanks!

Comment: You need to define what you mean by `top posts`. If you mean the posts with a high amount of view, then you must install a plugin to store the post hits/views and then query it using `WP_Query`.

Comment: I have searched online and got some codes which I tried also, but those don't help me with information to call top/most viewed posts on my site.  I followed these [lines of code](https://www.reviewsdir.com/how-to-display-random-posts-in-wordpress-to-increase-engagement) from site called reviewsdir. Is there any modification required?

Answer (score 1):

A standard WordPress install doesn't keep track of visits to pages/posts. So without a plugin there's no way to know which posts/pages are visited most often. As to [finding random posts](https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Order_.26_Orderby_Parameters) that's as simple as:

```
$args = array(
  'post_type' => array( 'post', 'page', 'my-custom-post-type' )
  'orderby' => 'rand',
  );
$query = new WP_Query ($args);
```

Comment: I want to do this without a plugin. How to store visits/pageviews data?

Comment: You're asking to extend WordPress functionality, so if you are unwilling to add a plugin (which could be a plugin of your own making), the only other option would be to code the functionality into a theme. You could add code to your theme's header.php that would send a pageview to the database each time it renders. In functions.php you'd set up an extra column in the wp_posts table to store the data, and in the header you'd have code that identifies the post ID currently being viewed, pulls the current hit count from wp_posts, and increments it.